# Dinamically manipulate component structure with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following json structure:

```
const componentObject = (
    <Box>
      <SectionBox />
    </Box>
  )
```

And inside of `SectionBox`:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function SectionBox() {
  return <div>
    content here
  </div>
}
```

Is there a way to get access to `div` and its height using javascript ? I am building a magazaine layout and I need to make components (and its childs) to fit within a 'page' based its height. So, I was wondering if this is possible.

I tried taking a look at the componentObject object definition, but the tree structure it contains, only goes up to SectionBox, from there `props.children` is not defined. Do I need to render it first? Can you recomend a better approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "json structure"? That's a variable with JSX elements...

Comment: You probably want CSS to deal with this. Take a look [at the Flexbox model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Comment: You can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to access the component in javascript

Comment: @charchit I tried but no luck. The json does not contain all the `props.children` set

Comment: what do you mean by "json". Which json? it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. As @Andy said it seems css would be more better option for design. Please be clear.